# Odd remark behavior

Tags: batch-file

If you have a remark before the end of a block it gives a error. `) was unexpected at this time`

example code:

```
@echo off
set x=1
if %x% == 1 (
    set y=4
    set z=5
::Hello world
)
```

Does any one know way it has this error?

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/rem.html  here you can find an explanation...

Comment: A `::` on the line before a `close bracket` has been noted to be a problem.  You can use `REM` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use :: for remarks when inside brackets (). You must instead use REM

```
@echo off
set x=1
if %x% == 1 (
    set y=4
    set z=5
rem Hello world
)
```

Comment: That is not quite a true statement. It is possible to use `::` as comments within a block, but with certain restrictions. I don't remember the precise rules, but generally a `::` comment within a block must be followed by a valid uncommented command on the next line. It is *recommended* that `::` comments within blocks not be used because the rules are not widely understood.